# Adding background and centering it without any repeats

Tags: html, css, xml, image

I am trying to insert a background image and have it so that it does not repeat itself and the image is centered. Here is the XSL coding i have used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/countries">
<html>
<body background ="bg_locale.jpg">
<font color="white">
    <xsl:for-each select="country">

    <xsl:value-of select="countryname"/><br/>

    </xsl:for-each>
</font>
</body>
</html>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are writing HTML within your XSL template. There are many ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, here is the simplest:

Instead of using the HTML "background" element, you may try using the "style" attribute. Eventually, you will want to have this style information separated from the content, but I imagine that this is coming later in the course :) The style attribute accepts a syntax called CSS (Cascading Style Sheets). Without getting too deep into it, try something along these lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/countries">
<html>
<body style="background: url('bg_locale.jpg') no-repeat center center">
<font color="white">
    <xsl:for-each select="country">

    <xsl:value-of select="countryname"/><br/>

    </xsl:for-each>
</font>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can find more information about CSS backgrounds here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: Thank you so much for that. That was a great help to me. it not only helped me with the mentioned problem but also triggered ideas of how to complete many other elements and tasks of the XSL doc. 
Again thank you.